# DRY & BEM clarfication

Tags: html, sass, bem

I'm using the BEM approach but want to know if my scss due to it looks bad and wondering if its bad for performance. I'm styling '.description' and '.title' a few times but its within different modifier sections, can this cause concern? Can I use one class for all '.title' and '.description'. If so how to use this within BEM?

Here is my scss:

```
.section {
  padding: 10rem 0 0 0;
  @include for-tablet-landscape-up {
    padding: 12rem 0 0 0;
  }

  //TEAM:
  @include modifier('team') {
    text-align: center;
    .section__title {
      text-align: left;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }

  //EXPERIENCE:
  @include modifier('experience') {
    .experience {
      margin-bottom: 3.125rem;
      &:last-of-type{
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      @include for-tablet-portrait-up{
        margin-bottom: 5.625rem; 
      }
      .line {
        width: 12%;
        height: 1px;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: -9px;
        left: -3px;
      }
      @include element('title'){
        font-size: 1.875rem;
        font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
        margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
      }
      @include element('description'){
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: $color-offset--light-grey;
      }
    }
  }

  //FIRM OVERVIEW:
  @include modifier('firm-overview'){
    .firm-overview{
      margin-bottom: 6.25rem;
      &:last-of-type{
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2){
        margin-left: 42.5%;
      }
      @include element('number'){
        font-size: 1.75rem;
        font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
        margin-bottom: 2.8125rem;
      }
      @include element('title'){
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        color: $color-offset--green;
        letter-spacing: .3rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-bottom: 3.125rem;

        @include for-tablet-landscape-up{
          margin-bottom: 6.25rem;
        }
      }
      @include element('description'){
        font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
      }
    }
  }

  //COMMUNICATION:
  @include modifier('communication'){
    .communication{
      @include element('description'){
        font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        color: $color-offset--light-grey;
      }
    }
  }

  .block-holder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  @include element('top-line') {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.5rem;
    left: 0;
    background-color: $color-offset--green;
    width: 37%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  @include element('tagline') {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.55rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: .7rem;
    font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
  }
  @include element('title') {
    font-family: $type-font--cormorant-garamond;
    font-size: 2.175rem;
    margin-bottom: 5.625rem;
    line-height: 1;
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    @include modifier('block') {
      line-height: 1.1;
      span:last-of-type {
        line-height: .8;
      }
    }
  }
  @include element('description') {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5.625rem;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time and guidance. Means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to "compile" you sass and got the following css:

```
.section {}
.section_team .section__title {}
.section_experience .line {}
.section_experience .section__title {}
.section_experience .section__description {}
etc.
```

And there are some problems with BEM approach.
At first modifier of the block affects the element. Not shure this is huge problem, but it would be better to add modifiers directly to elements. But if elements are not nested within each other its okey.

And the second problem is modifier of the one block affetcs the other block `.section_experience .line {}`. Good practice is to use mixes in this case:
Instead of `.section_experience .line {}` try

**Css:**

```
.section__line {}
```

**Html:**

```
div.section__line.line
```

---

**IMHO**
It seems to me, it's overcomplication to call mixins each time to add elements and modifiers. Perhaps, it's easy to just write `&__` or `&_`.